# IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity - What is wrong?

Tags: android, listview, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to create a listview populated by items that have multiple clickable layouts inside them. In this context, the listview is a list of contacts. Each row in the listview represents a separate contact, and each button on the listview item should trigger an action related to that contact - eg, *view* and *book appointment*.

The XML for each listview item:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutBookAppt"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector_flatcolour"
    android:onClick="newAppt" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/apptNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/appt_new" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutInfo"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/layoutBookAppt"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/layoutBookAppt"
    android:onClick="viewCustomer"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector_flatcolour" >

    <!-- Various contact information here, name, number etc -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

My adapter:

```
public class CustListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<Customer> customers;
Context ctx;

public CustListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Customer> custs) {
    this.ctx = context;
    this.customers = custs;
}  

static class ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout info;
    LinearLayout book;
    TextView name;
    TextView number;
    int pos; // Not sure if this is the best approach
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Customer customer = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) { //inflate convertView and populate viewHolder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.pos = position;
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.customer_info, parent, false);
        viewHolder.info = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutInfo);
        viewHolder.book = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutBookAppt);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblCustName);
        viewHolder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblNumber);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);        
    }
    else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 

        // set the textviews here
    return convertView;
    }
/* Other mandatory functions here */    
}
```

And finally, the relevant parts of my activity:

```
public class CustListActivity extends Activity {

ListView lstCustomers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cust_list);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    lstCustomers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custlist);
    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {

    // Populate arraylist 'customers' with cursor from database

    lstCustomers.setAdapter(new CustListAdapter(this, customers));
}

public void newAppt(View view)
{
    if (view == null)
        Gen.popup("View is null");
    else
    {
        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        Gen.popup("book " + String.valueOf(vh.pos));
    }
}

public void viewCustomer(View view)
{
    if (view == null)
        Gen.popup("View is null");
    else
    {
        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        Gen.popup("view " + String.valueOf(vh.pos));
    }
}
}
```

Exception in logcat:

```
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3704)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3699)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  ... 11 more
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.example.myapp.CustListActivity.newAppt(CustListActivity.java:110)
09-26 09:37:38.070: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  ... 14 more
```

So basically what I am trying to do is be able to get *two* bits of information when the user presses a listview item.

1. The row position
2. The layout that was pressed

I can get these details separately fine, but trying to get **both** is proving to be hard. I can have separate onClick events trigged via XML, but cannot work out how I can then find out the position of the row which was pressed. Also I can get the row position by setting an `onItemClickListener`, but this only triggers when the list item itself is pressed, but not any views within it.

With my `newAppt()` and `viewCustomer()` functions, I am trying to get the row position using `getTag()` (I'm not sure if this is the best approach but I'm trying anything) - however `getTag()` will ALWAYS return null, which has me at a complete loss.

Am I on the right track? If not, was is the best way of getting *both* the row and the view that was pressed?

(Edit: `Gen.popup` is my own short-hand method for TOAST).

Comment: Post your logcat output.

Comment: Logcat is so nice with you: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` at `com.example.myapp.CustListActivity.newAppt(CustListActivity.java:110)`

Comment: So who is `Gen` ? because it seems to be null

Comment: `Gen.popup()` is my own short-hand function for making a TOAST pop up :) Sorry for not making that clear. Edited the question.

Comment: @gunar The line it refers to is `Gen.popup(String.valueOf(vh.pos));`. The problem lies on the line before - `view.getTag()` is always returning null, so the `ViewHolder` object is null too.

Comment: No, that's not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below code

```
ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
```

to

```
final int position = listview.getPositionForView((View) view.getParent());
```

This line gives you the position which you have clicked.

Comment: Before, I tried `int pos = listview.getPositionForView(view)`, but it was returning false positions when views started getting recycled. But changing `view` to `view.getParent()` works amazingly! Thank you very much, thats all I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the `onClick` attribute for `@+id/layoutBookAppt` layout to `newAppt` method. In there, indeed, `getTag()` is null. But it's not the same tag of ListView children views. That is the tag of `LinearLayout`.

So you're doing something that makes no sense ... I am responding with another question: what do you intend to do with this method?

Comment: `But it's not the same tag of ListView children views. That is the tag of LinearLayout.` <<< Thank you very much for explaining this to me - I hadn't fully grasped what `getTag()` actually did. Jitesh helped me solve the problem, but +1 for the extra information - thanks :)